# Set viewBox(with Raphael) on mouse wheel to zoom in/out

Tags: svg, raphael

I have drawn few shapes like rectangle and circle using Raphael.
Here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ta8jQ/65/

The zoom function is show below:

```
function doZoom(coords, factor) {
   //transform real coordinates into viewbox coordinates
   debugger;
   x =  Number(viewbox[0]) + Number(coords.x / zoom);
   y =  Number(viewbox[1]) + Number(coords.y / zoom);

   if (factor < 0) {
     factor = 0.95;
   } else {
      factor = 1.05;
   }

   var z = ((zoom || 1) * factor) || 1;
   zoom = z;

   //zoom viewbox dimensions
   viewbox[2] = bbox.width / zoom;
   viewbox[3] = bbox.height / zoom;

   //transform coordinates to new viewbox coordinates
   viewbox[0] = x - coords.x / zoom;
   viewbox[1] = y - coords.y / zoom;

   paper.setViewBox.apply(paper, viewbox,true);
 }
```

I have a "**Fit to Screen**" button which shows all the shapes if it is drawn beyond the viewport (i.e visible drawing area). The "Fourth Circle" is a circle which has center (-50,-50). So on click "Fit to screen" all the shaped are visible.

Also zoom in and out is implemented on mouse wheel, but the problem I faced is: before Fit to Screen" button is clicked the zoom in/out on mouse wheel works fine. But as I click on Fit to screen button, and try to zoom at any point..there is sudden change in the zoom level. Say if you have first zoom out and clicked Fit to Screen and try to zoom First Circle using mouse wheel. The zoom is at the previous state(i.e zoom out state).But i need to zoom first circle as my mouse pointer is poiting First circle from the current zoom level(i.e Stretch Level of zoom).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If someone might facing same issue this might be the solution. Here I resolved above issue. Here is the link [link] http://jsfiddle.net/Ta8jQ/75/

Comment: You can also use raphael-pan-zoom plugin (https://github.com/escobar5/raphael-pan-zoom) that enables pan and zoom functionnalities, it's simple and it works fine!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG zoom with mouse wheel inside HTML document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073324/svg-zoom-with-mouse-wheel-inside-html-document)